# My equals method output is true while it should be false

Tags: java, methods, equals

I am writing a code and am following all instructions given to me. All the codes and methods look fine when I run the program but the equal method! Based on the instructions, I am supposed to get false when the tested asks if point (a, b)---(c, d) is equals to (e, f)---(g, h), but I get true. Can Anyone give me an idea where I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

```
 /**
     * The equals method should return true if the given object is equal to the
     * the Object passed in.  Note that this method receives an Object; there is
     * a particular way that this method should be implemented (see notes from class).
     *
     * Notice that two Segments are equal even if their endpoints are swapped
     *  i.e.: (1, 2)---(3, 4) == (3, 4)---(1, 2)
     */

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //if (obj instanceof Segment) {
            //Segment other = (Segment) obj;
            //return p1 == other.getP1() && p2 == other.getP2();
        //}
        //else {

            //throw new IllegalArgumentException("undefined");
        //}

        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof Segment))
            return false;

        else if(obj.getClass() != this.getClass()){
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            Segment S = (Segment)obj;
            if(this.getP1() == S.getP1() &&
                    this.getP2() == S.getP2());
            return true;


            //else if(obj.getP1() != this.getP1() &&
                //  obj.getP2() != this.getP2());
        //  return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show the Segment class, please show how you try to test equality.

Comment: Joshua Bloch tells you how to properly implement equals and hashCode in Chapter 3 of "Effective Java".

Comment: this: `if(obj.getClass() != this.getClass())` will not reliably work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(this.getP1() == S.getP1() &&
                this.getP2() == S.getP2());
                                          ^
```

Take out this semicolon.

Then you will also need to return a value if the `if` statement isn't met.

*Edit*

Currently your `if` statement is serving no purpose. Take out the semicolon so that the following return statement is qualified by the `if`. Then after that add a `return false` that will be applied if the `if` statement isn't met.

Like this:

```
if (this.getP1()==S.getP1() && this.getP2()==S.getP2()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Or, put more simply:

```
return (this.getP1()==S.getP1() && this.getP2()==S.getP2());
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hacked! You can use ＋1 with ＋ symbol. Muahahahahaha

Comment: If I remove semicolon I will get more errors! I use a tester which is given to me by my instructor to test my code. There are 6 tests done on my equals method, which if I remove the semicolon all of them will fail. For example I am expected to get false when tester tests the (a, b) and (c, d) if equals null, but I get java.lang.Error: unresolved compilation problem after I remove the semicolon!

Comment: @Ava I've added some more detailed instruction into my answer for you.

Comment: I have tried all of them but still not passing the test. It passed 6 out of 8!

Comment: I changed the code to what you said, and now, it passed all tests but the one I had originally problem with. In output it says: Testing (1, 2)---(3, 2) if equals (5, 6)---(7, 6). Then it says: expected: false,  Got: True.  I am so confused. Thank you though for your answer!